# rsProcessingError - Reporting Services Error - rsErrorReadingNextDataRow

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have ran into a strange issue in one of my SSRS reports. I get the following error:

> ```
> "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> cannot read the next data row for the dataset Defect_Summary. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)"
> ```

Whenever I run this dataset's query in query designer, or in management studio, the query runs fine. However, when I run the report in report builder or on the server I get the above error. After researching I have found that the issue has something to do with my parameter.

I have a parameter `@PO` (Production Order) where the user will provide an 8 digit number i.e. 11002575. In my query I have the following line: `OrderNr / 10000 = @PO`. In the database, `OrderNr` is of type `bigint` and will have a value such as 110025750020. I divide this number by 10000 so that the 8 digit `@PO` parameter equals the `OrderNr` such as 11002575.00 = 11002575. I used to use `LEFT(OrderNr, 8)`, but found it slowed down the query so this division has worked better for me.

Anyway, here's the strange part: When I first encountered this error, and after researching, I changed my parameter to type integer (from text). This fixed the problem temporarily and the report ran fine. Then I encountered it again, so I changed the type back to text, and again, it fixed the problem temporarily and the report ran fine. I keep going back and forth with this temporary fix and have not been able to find a permanent resolution to this error, it just keeps coming back after a while of working and then all I know to do is keep going back and forth from integer to text. Can anyone help me resolve this error permanently?

Comment: This OrderNr / 10000 = @ PO will slowdown your query. Please change to OrderNr  =  10000 * @ PO.

Comment: @PeterHe But `OrderNr <> 10000 * @ PO`. OrderNr is `110025750020` but 10000 * @PO is `110025750000`, they are different by 20.

Comment: @charlind Are you casting the result of `OrderNr / 10000` to an `int`? because otherwise you'll get a float. Try `CAST(OrderNr / 10000 AS INT) = @PO` and keep @PO as an integer.

Comment: @ChrisLatta I see.

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to trace the db calls? Add start and complete for the call, run the report, and you can narrow down the issue to database or SSRS

Comment: Also anything helpful in the SSRS log?

Comment: How is the system's OrderNumber dependent on the PO number? Is the PO number your company's PO number issued to a vendor? If that's the case, just create a PO Number field in the order table with the 8-digit PO number (on INSERT when the order number is created). That will eliminate the need to constantly calculate the PO number.